# Heroku CLI only works from root

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface

I'm not sure why, but I can only run the Heroku CLI from root, not from a user.

When I run from user I get

```
>>heroku -v
```

and that's it. Nothing comes, nothing happens, it just freezes.

However when I open a new terminal window and change to root, it works fine

```
>>sudo su
Password:
>>heroku -v
heroku-cli/6.15.26 (darwin-x64) node-v9.6.1
>>
```

I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling over and over again, I've used the Heroku direct download, as well as Homebrew, but I can't get it to work. I'm not really sure what I did to break my CLI, but how do I fix it? Where should I even look to see what the actual problem is?

UPDATES:

I've also changed shell types, and that did nothing to fix the issue either. The shell lists `Terminal -- node /usr/local/bin/heroku -v` at the top, if that helps.

As per the comments below, we tried copying the directory that the root user uses into my `.local/share` but this did not solve the problem either.

Further, I opened my activity monitor, and any time I try to run Heroku, it shows that `node` is taking up 95-100% of my CPU.

Comment: Are you sure you have installed it while a non-root user?

Comment: Yeah, I've been using it for nearly a year now without issue. I'm honestly not sure what I did to break it.

Comment: Try running `chown -R <nonroot-user> ~/.local/share/heroku` and `chown -R <nonroot-user> ~/Library/Caches/heroku`, where `<nonroot-user>` is the the user with which you are unsuccessfully trying to run the CLI, then try running the CLI again. Does that work?

Comment: If that doesn't work, while the non-root user, try `heroku auth:logout`, then `heroku login` and re-enter your Heroku credentials when prompted.

Comment: `chown -R <nonroot-user> ~/.local/share/heroku` return directory not found. Change owner worked on the second file. No fix, and `heroku auth:logout` just froze up the same way `heorku -v` does.

Comment: Hm...now we may be getting somewhere. What do you see when you `cd ~/.local/share` and `ls`?

Comment: That returns `NuGet` and nothing else. Though I think my heroku path is `/usr/local/bin/heroku`

Comment: Is there a `heroku` directory in `~/.local/share` when you're logged in as root user?

Comment: Well, would you look at that... yes, there is. `ls` returns `heroku`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165922/discussion-between-223seneca-and-martin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent nearly 12 days chatting with heroku staff. It turns out if your `.netrc` file is long (mine was 1.9 million lines), their parser has issues reading it.

Solution:

```
$ rm ~/.netrc
$ heroku login
```

Once the file is removed and you re-login it will create a new `.netrc` file without issues.

Why this happens:

My crontab uses an `expect` script to login to the blank environment. If you login over, and over and over, the `.netrc` file becomes huge.